# Windows XP Automatic Updates caught in a loop

Tags: windows-xp, windows-update

Win XP SP3 32-bit

I have Windows automatic updates on.  Each time i start my computer it tells me i have 4 new updates to install which are...

.NET framework 2.0 SP2  (KB974417)
.NET framework 3.5 SP1 and .NET framework 2.0 SP2 (KB979909)
.NET framework 2.0 SP2 (KB982524)
.NET framework 3.5 SP1 (KB982168)

here's the problem.  If i download and install them (when my computer shuts down) next time i start it up again the i'm told the same 4 updates are available for download.  It does this every time i restart my computer?

I can't seem to glean much from the event viewer so any ideas how i can start to combat this problem would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you've installed them try the following:

Change the update options to "ask" - Notify me but don't automatically download or install them - from Control Panel > Automatic Updates.

Then when it tells you there are updates select **Custom**. This should give you a dialog where you can select the updates you want. Deselect these 4 and continue.

Hopefully the next time you restart there shouldn't be any updates waiting.

Reset the Automatic Updates to your preferred method.

Alternatively you could go to the Windows Update site and either ignore them from there, or (which is what I'd try first) install them again from there and hope that this sets their install state correctly.

Comment: Thanks i'll give that a go.  I already tried installing them from the windows update site but the same thing happens

Answer (score 1):

What I've done in the past when I get this sort of issue is to download the specific update from Microsoft website instead from the Automatic Updates.

Once it's downloaded into your machine install it and restart the machine. Automatic Updates will see that you already have that installed and won't ask you to reinstall.

Here is where you can download them directly:

[KB974417](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=491874d4-5eea-4545-9b7d-3861857c862e&displaylang=en)

[KB979909](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=43810ead-1fcc-4a97-ad82-00ee42c27bad)

[KB982524](http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/2/6/426111FA-E964-44A1-B84E-90EAB1DE3EC8/NDP30SP2-KB982524-x86.exe)

[KB982168](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=4c2f99f6-53b9-454d-bb47-d1a1fcd58f66)

Comment: this seems to have done the trick - thank you

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft Baseline Security Analyser](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/cc184923.aspx)

Might be an alternative to using Windows Update, I've had an XP machine in the past which has refused to use Windows Update for no good reason.

It is possible to run this utility and it provides links to the windows update items that you need to install on the machine.

It's a bit of a pain having to download each file individually and install it but this cured the "hiccup" for me and enabled me to start using Windows Update again.

Answer (score 0):

Check this Microsoft [technote](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/906602) out.  I've used it in the past to troubleshoot problem update issues.  Good luck!

Comment: More of a direct troubleshooter to this particular problem, linked to in your article

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910339

Answer (score 0):

**TO FIX goto**,

[**Microsoft Support KB 2262911**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2262911)

Move down the page and do the work around.  **Works great**.

THE PROBLEM IS:

The error occurs because the underlying •NET Framework 2.0 SP2 Network Client Library feature layer is not updated when the Windows Communication Foundation feature layer is updated to use the new type. The underlying •NET Framework 2.0 SP2 Network Client Library feature layer does not support this new type, and so this error is thrown.